# Using a boolean to control a do/while loop

Tags: loops, boolean, do-while

I am a beginning programmer learning the basics for the first time. I am trying to write a program which calculates the sum of the numbers 1-100 as long as a boolean is false.

Here is my code:

```
public class BooleanSum
{
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;
    boolean cond = false;
do
{
    ++count;
    total = total + count;
    if (count >= 100)
    {
        cond = true;
    }
} while (cond);
System.out.println(total);
```

Here is my output:
`1`

The output that I am looking for is 5050 as that is the correct sum.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which language is this? If this compiles I don't believe this is your code, given that you have your code directly in a class without function.

Comment: you got the loop condition wrong: `while(cond)` requires `cond` be `true` to iterate. Try `while(!cond)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code logic should within a function and probably within `Main()` function and in your case issue is in below code block

```
if (count >= 100)
{
    cond = true;
}
```

Which rather should be

```
while (count >= 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the entire code in the main function and change "while (cond)" to "while (!cond)". In your code, condition inside while is false that's why the code gets executed only once and then it exits the loop. That's why you get 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = 0;

for ( int count = 1; count <= 100; count++ )
  total += count;
```

Looks more simple.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the boolean - just make a switch of it

```
 public class BooleanSum {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;
    boolean cond = true;
    do {

        total = total + count;
        if (count >= 100) {
            cond = false;
        }
        count++;
    } while (cond);

    System.out.println(total);

 }
}
```